# How to change 05/02/1953 to just 1953 in R (ie., dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy)?

Tags: r, date, datetime, date-formatting

I'm trying to compare two time-based data sets. One simply has years written in the 'yyyy' format, but the other one has 'dd/mm/yyyy'. Is there a way to convert all these to the simple year format?

Comment: Try `format(as.Date("05/02/1953", "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")`

Comment: Or take the substring: `substr("05/02/1953", 7, 11)`

Comment: Can someone please post these comments as one or more answers?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `lubridate` example:

```
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date

x <- "05/02/1953"

full_date <- lubridate::mdy(x)

class(full_date)
#> [1] "Date"

just_the_year <- year(full_date)

just_the_year
#> [1] 1953
```

Here is an example how to change the date in a whole data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- df %>%
    mutate(full_date = lubridate::mdy(x)) %>%
    mutate(just_the_year = year(full_date))
```

This will create two new columns in your data frame with the date as date and not string, and just the year.

Comment: does this just change it for that single unit? How would I change it for every date in the data set?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `format` from `base R`

```
as.integer(format(as.Date("05/02/1953", "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y"))
#[1] 1953
```

or with `strptime`

```
strptime("05/2/1953", "%d/%m/%Y")$year + 1900
#[1] 1953
```